# NotifyListeners is not rebuilding Consumer Widget

Tags: flutter, provider

I am trying to build a chat application. but whenever i call a method to update the chat list
everything works, but the widget is not rebuilding.

i have tried with context.read() and context.watch() methods        : Not working

i have tried with Provider.of(context,listen:true);  : Not working

i have tried with ChangeNotifierProxyProvider                       : Not working

only restarting rebuilds the ui. any help would be appreciated.

below is my code.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UsersProvider()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ChatProvider()),
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}
```

```
class UsersProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  UsersProvider(){
    getChats();
  }

  List<Chats> get chats=> _chats;

  List<Chats> _chats = [];


  Future getChats() async {
    final json = await UsersRepo().getChatLists();
    if (json == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (json['status']) {
      ChatListModel _model = ChatListModel.fromJson(json);
      _chats = _model.chats ?? [];
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

and the ui looks like

```
class ChatList extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.appBg,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Users'),
        backgroundColor: AppColors.appBgLight,
      ),
      body: chatListWidget(context),
    );
  }

  Widget chatListWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<UsersProvider>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, provider, Widget? child) {
        return ListView.separated(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
          itemCount: provider.chats.length,
          separatorBuilder: (c, i) => sbh(15),
          itemBuilder: (c, i) {
            Chats chat = provider.chats[i];
            return ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (c) {
                      return ChatScreen(
                        user: Users(
                            name: chat.receiver?.name, sId: chat.receiver?.id),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
                context.read<ChatProvider>().connectToUser(chat.receiver?.id);
              },
              leading:
              userImageWidget((chat.receiver?.name ?? "")[0].toUpperCase()),
              subtitle: Text(
                chat.lastMessage ?? "",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white70,
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),
              ),
              trailing: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 15,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      '${chat.unReadMessageCount}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
                    )),
              ),
              title: nameWidget(chat.receiver?.name ?? ''),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

}
```

Chats model class

```
class Chats {
  String? lastMessage;
  String? messageTime;
  int? unReadMessageCount;

  Chats(
      {this.lastMessage,
        this.messageTime,
        this.unReadMessageCount});

  Chats.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    lastMessage = json['lastMessage'];
    messageTime = json['messageTime'];
    unReadMessageCount = json['unReadMessageCount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['lastMessage'] = this.lastMessage;
    data['messageTime'] = this.messageTime;
    data['unReadMessageCount'] = this.unReadMessageCount;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try changing the stateless to a stateful of the ChatList class? And as an extra help, if you want to work in a chat I recommend you to find out about sockets.

Comment: It was a stateful widget. It's not matter. And I'm already using socket io in this project

Comment: Can you include `Chats`

Comment: Check the value of your "json['status']" of the response coming back from your repo, I suspect this might be the reason why is not actually triggering an update.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh chats is a simple model class it has nothing to do with the issue. if you still think its important, i will add that too. thanks

Comment: @BenjaminRodriguez json['status'] is just checking the response from server is success or not. it actually getting printed all the updated response. only problem is ui is not updating. thank you

Comment: I like to copy the full code and reproduce the issue

Comment: thank you for your support . im adding it to the question@YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `getChats()` method is failing before it can execute the notifyListeners method.

You see, any "if" statement in dart has to evaluate to a boolean, so unless `json['status']` returns true/false then the expression:

```
if (json['status'])
```

will throw an error that will end up in a failed future to be returned from your `getChats()` method.

It would be better to use a more specific condition for your if statement, maybe something like this (if `json['status']` is supposed to contain the http response code for the call):

```
if (json['status'] == 200)
```

In the case `json['status']` does indeed contains a boolean then there could be a few other reasons for your widget not rebuilding:

1- `json['status']` always evaluates to false

2- The call to get the chats fails but you get a silent error since you don't have a handler for the failed future that is returned by the getChats method

Comment: Hii,  json['status'] is a bool variable  if i print i can see the data coming. this code is not wrong in any way because, if its wrong it wont build the ui even for the first time. i think you haven't understood the issue. everything here is working fine except, after i making some changes i am calling this getChats()  api again and it brings new data (i printed it and its there), but its not updating the ui even after calling notifyListeners()

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, It sound like a race condition, The ChangeNotifierProvider has to subscribe to the ChangeNotifier's object but because you are making the call to get the chats in the constructor of the UsersProvider object you might be calling "notifyListeners" before the ChangeNotifierProvider had the chance to subscribe to listen for changes.